# Pseudo-Riemannian metrics on CR manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

While studying an (essentially linear-algebraic) problem, I faced the following construction. For a Hermitian manifold $(X, h)$ and $Y \subset X$ a real (say codimension $1$) submanifold, denote by $H$ the usual CR distribution on $Y$, and by $L$ its orthogonal complement inside $TY$ w. r. t. the real part of $h$ (viewed as a Riemannian metric). Then define on $Y$ a pseudo-Riemannian metric $g$ by setting $g|_L = \mathrm{Re}~h_L$ and $g|_H=-\mathrm{Re}~h|_H$. Is this construction known, and if it is, what is the actual geometry beyond it? Does it have a special name, or whatever?